# Refreshing a Navigation Bar Background Color View after button click

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am not sure how to handle.  I have tried a few was and have been unable to refresh a view.

I am doing themes in my application that allow the user to click a button and change the color theme throughout the application.  This is working as intended with the exception of the Navigation bar view that I created to set the background color for the navigation bar.

```
import SwiftUI

struct NavigationViewBackgroundColor: View {
    
    // THEME
    @ObservedObject var theme = ThemeSettings.shared
    var themes: [Theme] = themeData
    
    @Environment(\.refresh) private var refresh
    
  init() {
    let coloredAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    coloredAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
      coloredAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(Color(themes[self.theme.themeSettings].themePrimaryColor))//.darkGray
    coloredAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor(Color(themes[self.theme.themeSettings].themeSecondaryColor))]
    coloredAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor(Color(themes[self.theme.themeSettings].themeSecondaryColor))]
    
    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = coloredAppearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = coloredAppearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = coloredAppearance
   
    
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 4)
      
  } //:END OF INIT
     
  
  var body: some View {
   NavigationView {
    } //:END OF NAVIGATION VIEW
   .navigationBarTitle("",displayMode: .inline)
   .navigationBarHidden(true)
  } //:END OF BODY/VIEW
} //:END OF STRUT

struct NavigationViewBackgroundColor_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    NavigationViewBackgroundColor()
  }
}
```

This works as originally intended before I implemented a color theme option. Now the app has to be closed and reopened to get the navigation bar color and or this view to refresh.

I am not sure how to handle.  I tried to create a @State var updater: Bool = false  and a function to toggle to see it would force and update.  No luck.

All other view are updating correctly and changing the color theme when the user choose a different one with the exception of this one.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Here is the view that I am using to display the navigationViewBackgroundColor view that I would like to refresh once the user choose a different color.

```
    import SwiftUI


struct AppView: View {
    
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES


// THEME
    @ObservedObject var theme = ThemeSettings.shared
    var themes: [Theme] = themeData
    
    
    // MARK: - BODY
    
    var body: some View {
        

                NavigationView {
                    VStack {
                        
                        ZStack {
                            
                          Text(“Navigation View”)
                            .foregroundcolor(Color(themes[self.theme.themeSettings].themePrimaryColor))
                            
                        } //: END OF ZSTACK
                        
                    } //: END OF BODY VSTACK
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .accentColor(Color(themes[self.theme.themeSettings].themeSecondaryColor))
                    .background(Color(themes[self.theme.themeSettings].themePrimaryColor))
                    .navigationBarTitle("",displayMode: .inline)
                    .navigationBarItems(
                    NavigationViewBackgroundColor()
                } //: END OF NAVIGATION VIEW
                .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
.onAppear {
                //:THIS IS ONLY FOR TESTING REMOVE BEFORE LAUNCH
                if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Theme") {
                    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "Theme")
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(0, forKey: "Theme")
                } else {
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(0, forKey: "Theme")
                } //:END OF IF FOR THEME THIS WILL SET A DEFAULT
            } //:END OF ONAPPEAR
```

Here is the themes data that stores the color schemes.

```
The model

mport SwiftUI

// MARK: - THEME MODEL

struct Theme: Identifiable {
  let id: Int
  let themeName: String
  let themePrimaryColor: String
  let themePrimaryLightColor: String
  let themeSecondaryColor: String
  let themeAccentColor: String 
}

The data

import SwiftUI

// MARK: - THEME DATA

let themeData: [Theme] = [
    Theme(id: 0, themeName: "Pink Theme", themePrimaryColor: "Theme-Pink-Primary-Color", themePrimaryLightColor: "Theme-Pink-Primary-Light-Color", themeSecondaryColor: "Theme-Pink-Secondary-Color", themeAccentColor: "Theme-Pink-Accent-Color"),
    Theme(id: 1, themeName: "Blue Theme", themePrimaryColor: "Theme-Blue-Primary-Color", themePrimaryLightColor: "Theme-Blue-Primary-Light-Color",themeSecondaryColor: "Theme-Blue-Secondary-Color", themeAccentColor: "Theme-Blue-Accent-Color"),
    Theme(id: 2, themeName: "Green Theme", themePrimaryColor: "Theme-Green-Primary-Color", themePrimaryLightColor: "Theme-Green-Primary-Light-Color",themeSecondaryColor: "Theme-Green-Secondary-Color", themeAccentColor: "Theme-Green-Accent-Color"),
    Theme(id: 3, themeName: "Orange Theme", themePrimaryColor: "Theme-Orange-Primary-Color", themePrimaryLightColor: "Theme-Orange-Primary-Light-Color",themeSecondaryColor: "Theme-Orange-Secondary-Color", themeAccentColor: "Theme-Orange-Accent-Color")
]


The observable object that will trap the color choice

import Foundation
import SwiftUI

// MARK: - THEME CLASS

final public class ThemeSettings: ObservableObject {
  @Published public var themeSettings: Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Theme") {
    didSet {
      UserDefaults.standard.set(self.themeSettings, forKey: "Theme")
    } //:END OF SET
  } //:END OF PUBLISHED
  
  private init() {}
  public static let shared = ThemeSettings()
} //:END OF CLASS
```

Comment: Hi @brandon. Please add sample code that demonstrates the problem, _that can be run by someone trying to solve it_ . Your code contains undefined objects. Please read [mcve]

Comment: OK, so please add a [mcve]

Comment: I added the view that is calling the NavigationViewBackgroundColor view.  I would like to be able to refresh this view once the user choose a different color.  I am not sure how to make that view refreshable.

Comment: What is `Theme`? What is `ThemeSettings`? What is `ViewRouter`, etc. No-one can run your code while you have undefined objects in it. I'll ask again, please supply a [mcve]. If you don't know what that is, please click the link and read the page.

Comment: I removed the view router out as it's not necessary.  I added the theme data and I added an onappear to the navigation view that sets the default color scheme. you can manually change it to the different themes. They are only string values that align with a saved color set in my assets folder.  You can assign any color to the theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is went away from using the NavigationBackgroundView and add a zStack to the app view and then set the theme color there while ignoring the safe edges.  That set the background of the preexisting navigation bar and updates every time the user changes the color.

```
ZStack {
  Color(themes[self.theme.themeSettings].themePrimaryColor)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
  VStack{
    Text("Everything else went inside here")
  }
}
```